# let returnTrip = Page(story: .ReturnTrip)?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

in the  let returnTrip = Page(story: .ReturnTrip) it give us error. ı am really don't know whyyy
1

```
enum Story {

case ReturnTrip (String)
case TouchDown
case Homeward
case Rover (String)
case Cave
case Crate
case Monster
case Droid (String)
case Home

var rawValue: String {
    switch self {
    case .ReturnTrip: return "ReturnTrip"
    case .TouchDown: return "TouchDown"
    case .Homeward: return "Homeward"
    case .Rover: return "Rover"
    case .Cave: return "Cave"
    case .Crate: return "Crate"
    case .Monster: return "Monster"
    case .Droid: return "Droid"
    case .Home: return "Home"
    }
}

}
```

2

```
extension Story {

var artwork: UIImage {
    return UIImage (named: self.rawValue)!
}

var soundEffectURL : NSURL {
    let fileName: String

    switch self {
    case .Droid, .Home: fileName = "HappyEnding"
    case .Monster: fileName = "Ominous"
    default: fileName = "PageTurn"

    }

    let path = Bundle.main.path( forResource: fileName, ofType: "wav")!

    return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)


}
```

3

```
 var text: String {
    switch self {
    case .ReturnTrip(let name):
        return "On your return trip from studying Saturn's rings, you hear a distress signal that seems to be coming from the surface of Mars. It's strange because there hasn't been a colony there in years. \"Help me, \(name), you're my only hope.\""
```

and then

```
class Page {

let story: Story

typealias Choice = (title: String, page: Page)

var firstChoice: Choice?
var secondChoice: Choice?

init(story:Story) {
    self.story = story
}
```

}

```
extension Page {

func addChoice(title: String, story: Story) ->  Page {
    let page = Page (story: story)
    return addChoice (title:title, page:page)
}
```

and then

```
func addChoice(title: String, page: Page) -> Page {

    switch (firstChoice, secondChoice) {
    case (.some, .some): break
    case (.none, .none), (.none, .some):
    firstChoice = (title, page)
    case (.some, .none):
        secondChoice = (title, page)

    }
    return page
}
```

}

lastly

```
struct Adventure {
static var story: Page {
    let returnTrip = Page(story: .ReturnTrip)
    let touchdown = returnTrip.addChoice("Stop and Investigate", story: .TouchDown)
    let homeward = returnTrip.addChoice("Continue Home to Earth", story: .Homeward)
    let rover = touchdown.addChoice("Explore the Rover", story: .Rover)
    let crate = touchdown.addChoice("Open the Crate", story: .Crate)

    homeward.addChoice("Head back to Mars", page: touchdown)
    let home = homeward.addChoice("Continue Home to Earth", story: .Home)

    let cave = rover.addChoice("Explore the Coordinates", story: .Cave)
    rover.addChoice("Return to Earth", page: home)

    cave.addChoice("Continue towards faint light", story: .Droid)
    cave.addChoice("Refill the ship and explore the rover", page: rover)

    crate.addChoice("Explore the Rover", page: rover)
    crate.addChoice("Use the key", story: .Monster)

    return returnTrip

}
```

}

what is the problem above

what is the problem here in the

```
let returnTrip = Page(story: .ReturnTrip)
```

it say contextual member for .ReturnTrip

Comment: The full error message is `contextual member 'ReturnTrip' expects argument of type 'String'`  which clearly shows your error: `.ReturnTrip` expects an associated value, such as `.ReturnTrip("someString")`.

Comment: really u don't don't understand where is the problem bro :(

Comment: "someString" means  ???

Comment: @MuhammedHanifiAlma: *You* defined `case ReturnTrip (String)` in the enumeration, not me.

Comment: can u say how we can choose, ı really confused now.  ı try to understand

Comment: still not solve problem  :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of `.ReturnTrip(String)` tells the system that you need to associate a `String` value with the `enum`. But in your implementation, you didn't associated any value with your enum, that's why you are getting the error message.

Correct use of `.ReturnTrip (String)` will be something like:

```
let returnTrip = Page(story: .ReturnTrip("Midhun"))
```

Read more about [Associated enum values](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html)

**Note**: The same applies to `.Rover(String)` and `.Droid(String)` enum cases.

Comment: bravoooo brother. tnx for logical answer. i wiss the others give us logical answer like that. thanks.  :)